# How can I simulate poor internet connection when using flutter?

Tags: flutter, testing, connection

I know that there is a way on android, but I am using ios devices. I am also using a real device for development because some app features like photos and location. It would be very much appreciated if anyone could shed some light on this topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS go to `Settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner` to enable it.

If you want to enable Developer mode go to `Settings > Privacy and Security > Developer Mode` and turn on.